# Visual Studio error: Unable to load the stored procedure for editing

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, mariadb

I'm trying to start with MySQL and stored procedures. I'm a visual studio user and I found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html. I would like to use VS because of the debugging capabilities.

I installed both MySQL for Visual Studio and the connector. I can connect to the database, view the tables, view the stored procedures, ...

But when I double click a stored procedure I get an error: "Unable to load the stored procedure for editing". VS continues and shows a blank document. The same happens when I right click and select 'Alter routine'.

I don't know if it is important but I'm not using a MySQL installation but MySQL in XAMP (MariaDB).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is the mysql "user" in question `GRANTed` sufficient privileges?

Comment: I think so. I have not made any users. I use root without a password on localhost. I have not made any users or set a password.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify connection on your Server Explorer
And then check on checkbox "Save my password"

[image]

[image]